# Best way to move list Item with version history to another list SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, splistitem, version-history

I am working on one project, where I want archive list items (old records) to another list with version history. Both list have configuration and belong to same site collection.

We don't want to used any paid migration tool to do that.

Can you advice me How can we archive that? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

CSOM has all the tools you need to develop a custom solution to do that.
You could also rely on API, i think there is a way to get a file version collection, and from them you can upload\update iterating the objects.

Good Luck!